# Action Controller: Exception Caught [NoMethodError in ViewerController#show]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to click through a link in my navigation, but an error message appears.

> NoMethodError in ViewerController#show

The error points to the following path:

> /Users/ianmcdonald/Sites/beatsbymakii/app/controllers/viewer_controller.rb:5:in
>   `show'

This is the code that I have defined for the method.

```
class ViewerController < ApplicationController
    def show

    @page = Page.find_by_name(params[:name])
    @subpages = @page.subpages
    @pagetitle = @page.title
    login_required if @page.admin?
    end
end
```

Please help me as I havent a clue what to do next.

Comment: Is Page#subpages defined ? Isn't @page nil ?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether @page is returned as `nil`, by outputing it to console like this:

```
  def show
    @page = Page.find_by_name(params[:name])
    p "@pageeeeeeeee"
    puts @page.inspect
    @subpages = @page.subpages
    @pagetitle = @page.title
    login_required if @page.admin?
  end
```

I am almost sure this will be the case as there may not be a page with the specific name in the database.

Comment: the same message is still showing up wit the code you gave me to try?

Comment: @IanMcDonald..it was a code to check whether @page is nil..you have to check in the terminal window where you started the application server (by using command `rails s` or `ruby script/server`). There you may see `"@pageeeeeeeee"` and under that the value of `@page` variable..most probably it will be `nil`. I have edited my post with code to check if @page exists and do something else if it is nil